# A question from E.M Stein's book. How to analyze the Continuity of $z_{\epsilon}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

This is a problem from Stein's Complex Analysis, $f,g$ are holomorphic on $|z|≤1$, and $f(0)=0$,and vanishes nowhere on the unit disc. suppose $z_{\epsilon}$ is the zero of function $f_{\epsilon}=f(z)+\epsilon g(z)$,show that $\epsilon\rightarrow z_{\epsilon}$ is continous.
Well,the existence of zeros comes directly from the Rouché's Theorem,but for the continuity,I guess it needs a topological proof .searching for help

Comment: if f is continous，f maps an open set to an open set?

Comment: The question is actually answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651150/zeros-of-f-epsilonz-fz-epsilon-gz-with-f-and-g-holomorphic?rq=1